# How can I use python console while running a script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, terminal, reinforcement-learning

I'm using python for some reinforcement learning tasks. Sometimes (usually, actually) the agent fail and I suspect it to overfit on the dataset. For obvious speed reasons, the training is done without rendering, hence, I'm only able to watch it fail when training's done. Though I'm using prints, I think that I could maybe detect the moment it starts overfitting if I could watch the training. However, I do not want to sacrifice speed. Is there any way I can, via terminal and user input, call a function while the script is running and without blocking it ?
It would be something like an event, I suppose.

**EDIT** Maybe multiprocessing is a solution, as somebody suggested.

Here's my code. It does render, but I'm not sure it multiprocesses anything:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def drawing(y): 
    x = np.arange(y.shape[0])
    plt.cla()
    plt.bar(x,y)


process = Process(target = drawing)

s = env.reset()
process.start()
plt.show()
while True: 

    state_tensor = Variable(torch.Tensor(s)).unsqueeze(0)
    action, vals = a3.think(state_tensor, display= True, train = False)
    env.render()
    drawing(vals)  # the part I want to speed up 
    ns,r, done, _ = env.step(action)
    s = ns 
    if done: 
        s = env.reset()
```

Comment: None that I can think of. Your best bet might be to add a couple conditional breakpoints in appropriate places but once you hit a breakpoint you enter the debugger and it does block execution until you resume it.

Comment: Well, at least a tiny bit of speed must be sacrificed. If you define some type of "event" (like a variable set from the outside) you must check to see if the event is generated (variable set) every so often. Then you have to respond to the event one way or another. But if this does not happen to often, maybe this is OK? In that cse you should look into threading, where one thread is handling user IO and another thread is doing the calculation.

Comment: Indeed, I think multiprocessing could be a solution.